# Server throws "Is a directory" error but I expect it to be a directory

Tags: python, flask

I'm saving images into temporary directory on the server. I'm not including imports
as those aren't relevant to this problem:

```
@images_blueprint.route('/image/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    TEMP_DIR = os.getcwd()+f'/{secrets.token_hex(12)}/'
    os.mkdir(TEMP_DIR)
    image = request.files.get('image')
    if not image:
        return jsonify(response_obj), 400
    filename = secure_filename(image.filename)
    image.save(TEMP_DIR, filename) # <-- Error thrown here "Is a directory"
    # os.remove(TEMP_DIR)
```

I'm getting error on indicated line. The thing is I **expect** it to be a directory. Why
is it complaining ?

Comment: Did you look at https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage.save (API doc) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below check if there is an image in the request and return with 400 if there is image. It builds a path that is used in `save`

```
@images_blueprint.route('/image/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    image = request.files.get('image')
    if not image:
        return jsonify(response_obj), 400
    else:
        TEMP_DIR = os.getcwd()+f'/{secrets.token_hex(12)}/'
        os.mkdir(TEMP_DIR)
        filename = secure_filename(image.filename)
        image.save(os.path.join(TEMP_DIR,filename))
        #image.save(TEMP_DIR, filename) # <-- Error thrown here "Is a directory"
        # os.remove(TEMP_DIR)
```